# Change string to HH:MM:SS in PySpark

Tags: string, time, pyspark, type-conversion

I have Column "minutes" . i want change the column to hh:mm:ss format in PySpark

Input:

```
     minutes(string type)
     10
     20
     70
     90
```

output:

```
minutes(string type)    min_change
    10                  00:10:00
    20                  00:20:00
    70                  01:10:00
    90                  01:30:00
```

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  
[I downvoted because no attempt was made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column with `lit("00:00:00")` and cast it to `timestamp`. Convert the `minutes` to seconds and add it to the timestamp column. Finally, use `date_format()` to get your desired format:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("minutes", col("minutes").cast("int"))\
    .withColumn("min_change", lit("00:00:00").cast("timestamp"))\
    .withColumn("min_change", (F.unix_timestamp("min_change") + F.col("minutes")*60).cast('timestamp'))\
    .withColumn("min_change", date_format("min_change",'HH:mm:ss')).show()

+-------+----------+                                                            
|minutes|min_change|
+-------+----------+
|     10|  00:10:00|
|     20|  00:20:00|
|     70|  01:10:00|
|     90|  01:30:00|
+-------+----------+
```